# Problem accessing google drive with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I wrote a bot with GAS for Slack and everything works fine. Now I made a copy of the bot and it starts giving out weird error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." when I try to access a folder in Google drive. Since the code is exactly the same, I have no idea what the problem is.

```
//Create Pdf
function exportCurrentSheetAsPDF_() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MAIN_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var currentSheet = ss.getSheetByName(ASAKAWA_HOLIDAY_SHEET);
  var blob = getAsBlob(ss.getUrl(), currentSheet);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'YYYYMMddhhmmss');
  var pdfName = mergePdfName("休日", date, "浅川Only", "H");

  //Export pdf to google drive 008.2 Entertainment folder
  exportPdfToDrive(blob, pdfName);
  return pdfName;
}

function exportPdfToDrive(blob, fileName) {
  blob = blob.setName(fileName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID);  <--- This gives error
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
}

//Get spreadsheet as blob
function getAsBlob(url, sheet, range) {
  var exportUrl = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '')
      + "/export?exportFormat=pdf"
      + "&format=pdf"
      + "&size=A4"
      + "&portrait=true"
      + "&fitw=true"                  
      + "&sheetnames=false"
      + "&printtitle=false"
      + "&pagenum=false"
      + "&gridlines=false"
      + "&fzr=FALSE"      
      + "&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
    headers: { 
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
  })

  return response.getBlob();
}
```

Comment: Are you logged into multiple accounts? It happened to me couple of days back. I just logout from other account and logged into the account that has the srcipt

Comment: Hi, I am using the same account for both scripts.

Comment: Does it work if you make a copy of the copy? Are you a G Suite user?

Comment: I tried making a copy of a copy and it still doesn't work :(. I am not a G Suite user.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the code which can be used to reproduce this behaviour (specially where the `blob` comes from)?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the main post and showed more code, please tell me if you need anything!

Comment: The code I posted should be working fine, since it works perfectly on the original spreadsheet, just when I copied the spreadsheet suddenly I have problem with the G drive code.

Comment: @DarkWheel I cannot reproduce this behaviour, the script is exporting the file correctly. Have you checked if you can reproduce this using a different original spreadsheet?

Comment: It only works on the original spreadsheet, as soon as I make a copy everything stops working.

Comment: I didn't mean trying it on a copy, but creating a new spreadsheet and adding the corresponding content. Do you have a way of reliably reproducing this with a different file? Have you tried narrowing the scope of this issue? I'd suggest you to file a bug in Issue Tracker, but since you didn't provide any reproduction steps, I cannot see what can be done here.

Comment: Actually I tried making a new spreadsheet and copy everything over and commented out everything leaving just 1 line of code.

(  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID);  )

it works until I set it up as my Slack bot then suddenly it just stops working. I know the setting is not wrong since it is exactly the same as my working bot.